# android- How to add and delete objects to realm Database?

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to implement Favorite List in my Application. For that I am using realm as my database to store the Contents. I am able to add the contents successfully but when trying to remove the items crashes the app. I am trying to delete the objects using the primary key which is movieId variable. But it crashes the app.
Any Help is Appreciated.

Code for adding and removing the contents:

```
       mFavoriteButton.setOnFavoriteChangeListener(new MaterialFavoriteButton.OnFavoriteChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFavoriteChanged(MaterialFavoriteButton buttonView, boolean favorite) {
                if(!favorite) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.thejoker.yts", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("Fav Checked", false);
                    editor.commit();
                    RealmResults<FavoriteListRealm> results = mRealm.where(FavoriteListRealm.class).equalTo("realmMovieId", movieId).findAll();

                    mRealm.beginTransaction();
                    mResults.remove(results);
                    mRealm.commitTransaction();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Not a favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(favorite) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("com.thejoker.yts", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("Fav Checked", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    mRealm.beginTransaction();
                    FavoriteListRealm favorites = mRealm.createObject(FavoriteListRealm.class);
                    favorites.setRealmMovieId(movieId);
                    favorites.setRealmMovieTitle(movieTitle);
                    favorites.setRealmThumbnailUrl(movieUrlThumbnail);
                    favorites.setRealmMovieYear(movieYear);
                    mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(favorites);
                    mRealm.commitTransaction();
                    mResults = mRealm.where(FavoriteListRealm.class).findAllAsync();
                    Toast.makeText(MovieDetailsActivity.this, mResults.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the question? Please be clear!

Comment: How to delete objects from Realm. Thats my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
mRealm.beginTransaction();
mResults.remove(results);
mRealm.commitTransaction();
```

use `clear()` method (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#clear--)

```
mRealm.beginTransaction();
results.clear();
mRealm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: This method seems to be deprecated.

Comment: clear() is deprecated, you can use deleteAllFromRealm() instead

Answer (score 4):

Once the method `clear()` is deprecated, you should use:

```
realm.deleteAll()
```

or

```
results.deleteAllFromRealm()
```

Source: [Realm Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html#deleteAllFromRealm--)